# Как в блоке div расположить еще один div снизу справа в bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно в блоке, который должен быть расположен по центру экрана, поместить еще один блок, который надо расположить снизу справа, как это сделать? Уже всю голову сломал....

```
<div class="container-xxl mt-2 p-1" style="background-color: #242424; border-radius: 15px; width:1230px; height: 580px;">
    <div class="m-1" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; width:700px; height: 300px;">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте свои классы, если не знаете как сделать это на бутстрапе

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        .div-absolute {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-xxl mt-2 p-1" style="background-color: #242424; border-radius: 15px; width:100%; height: 400px;position: relative">
    <div class="m-1 div-absolute" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; width:200px; height: 200px;">
    
    </div>

</div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```